# Xeon phi co processor only mode using MPI, connection refused

Tags: mpi, xeon-phi

Typed command like below

```
$ mpiicpc -mmic -o Hello.MIC Hello.c
$ scp Hello.MIC mic0:/tmp/Hello.MIC
$ export I_MPI_MIC=enable
$ mpirun -n 2 -host mic0 /tmp/Hello.MIC
```

and I got this error

```
[proxy:0:0@mic0.local] HYDU_sock_connect (../../utils/sock/sock.c:268): unable to connect from "mic0.local" to "127.0.0.1" (Connection refused)
[proxy:0:0@mic0.local] main (../../pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:372): unable to connect to server 127.0.0.1 at port 46331 (check for firewalls!)
```

this is my host setup

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
172.31.1.1  mic0.local mic0 #Generated-by-micctrl
$ ssh mic0 cat /etc/hosts
172.31.1.254    host
172.31.1.1  mic0.local mic0
```

I did firewall off, and passward-less ssh connection.

and copied host mpi lib, and bin files to mic0.

what is the problem with this error?

please, give me some hints.

ps)I refered  Using the Intel® MPI Library on Intel® Xeon Phi™ Coprocessor Systems https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-the-intel-mpi-library-on-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-systems#prep

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is in the error message printed by Intel MPI hydra:

> unable to connect from "mic0.local" to "127.0.0.1" (Connection refused)

Please verify that you can ssh from mic0 to itself, so the commands:
$ ssh mic0.local
and
$ ssh localhost
executed from the card's OS should complete without requesting password authentication.

It may require setting up ssh keys (such as adding public key into .ssh/authorized_keys) on the card, especially if the /home filesystem is not mounted on card from the host. You may also need to check file permissions on ssh private key and authorized_keys: basically do everything you'd normally do for normal password-less authentication between two Linux machines.

Also, something which may help other issues: try making /etc/hosts be exact the same on the host and on Xeon Phi card, so, specifically add line:
172.31.1.254    host
on your host machine as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when I ssh from mic0 to localhost, [user@mic0 ~]$ssh localhost, then I log in mic 0. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options to try:

```
-iface mic0
-bootstrap ssh
-env I_MPI_DEBUG 9 PATH/BINARY
```

Comment: `mpiexec.hydra  -iface mic0 -n 2 -host  mic0 /tmp/Hello.MIC`  work for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some tips mentioned in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mpi-library-and-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-tips

The symptom you have looks like the one in #5. You may try "mpiexec.hydra -iface mic0 ..."